# Улучшение кода двух слайд-шоу на одной странице

Tags: javascript

На одной странице два слайд-шоу, они практически используют одни и тежи функции, но интуиция мне подсказывает, что мой код неправилен. Например функции previousSlide() и nextSlide() надо как-то преобразовать в одну

```
$(function(){

var imagesFace = []
var imagesHands = []

for(var i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
    imagesFace[i] = new Image();
    imagesHands[i] = new Image();
}

imagesHands[1].src = "/images/1.jpg"
 //и так далее
imagesHands[5].src = "/images/5.jpg"

imagesFace[1].src = "/images/1.jpg"
    //и так далее
imagesFace[5].src = "/images/5.jpg"

slideShowHands(imagesHands)
slideShowFace(imagesFace)
})

function slideShowHands(images){
 document.getElementById('hands_back').addEventListener('click', previousSlide, false)
 document.getElementById('hands_go').addEventListener('click', nextSlide, false)

var num = 1
var placeSlideImg = document.getElementById('hands_slide')

function nextSlide(event){}
function previousSlide(event){}

  function slideShowFace(images){
document.getElementById('face_back').addEventListener('click', previousSlide, false)
    document.getElementById('face_go').addEventListener('click', nextSlide, false)

var num = 1
var placeSlideImg = document.getElementById('face_slide')

function nextSlide(event){} 
function previousSlide(event){}
}
```

Comment: ужасный код 

- жуткая мешанина pure js и jQuery
- избыточное создание jQuery-объектов из DOM-елементов

даже браться править неохота

Comment: А вы думаете что это:

    ImagesFace[5].src = "/images/...." previousSlide

исполнится? :)  
Это опечатка или так должно быть?

Comment: Дико плюсую комменты)

Comment: это просто, продолжение путя.

Comment: @Spectre изменил код

Comment: Без точек с запятой код смотрится как недописанный.